# Change field from integer at String

Tags: vb.net

I have two tables in MS Access:

```
[TABEL_BRANCHE] (BRANCHE_Id Numeric, BRANCHE_Name Text)
[TABEL_WORKER] (WORKER_Id numeric, WORKER_Section numeric, WORKER_Gender Text )
```

`BRANCHE_Name` is filled by variable names like (COMPUTER, MOBILE, SPORT, BIBLIO, CHESS, etc ). The values in `WORKER_Section` map to the values in  `TABEL_BRANCHE.BRANCHE_Id`. `WORKER_Gender` contains either `MALE` `FEMALE`.

I have a form with a ComboBox (`ComboBox1`), a DatGridView (`DataGridView1`) and a Chart (`Chart1`). ComboBox1 is populated with the values from `BRANCHE_Name`.

When I choose an item in `ComboBox1`, `DataGridView1` will show the number of matching Males and Females. At the same time, `Chart1` will show graph of the Census.

My code all works very well without any fault, but I want to change the field `WORKER_Section` from numeric to text to show the original `BRANCHE_Name` data, and I can't make it work. My two tables do not have any relationship.

Comment: Gah, the SQL injection, it burns us!

Comment: Okay, this is so much more readable now. Questions that show a big wall of text, with no paragraph breaks, don't tend to get good answers.

Comment: Thank you Sir .. I am available for any question about subject.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't do this**

Currently, `WORKER_Section` is acting as a foreign key to `BRANCHE_Name`. That's *good schema design*. What you're asking to do will make things slower, increase maintenance, and break the de-facto relationship between the two tables.

Comment: But for personal reasons .. I want to change the field (WORKER_Section) from digit number .. by choosing names of the field (BRANCHE_Name).

Comment: Any suggestion..please